# Where is the hosts file for Windows Phone 8 emulator located?

Tags: networking, windows-8, windows-phone-8

Using the Windows Phone 8 emulator on Windows 8, how can I update the hosts file used by the emulator?

I have tried updating the Windows 8 hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts). This does not affect Internet Explorer within the Windows Phone 8 emulator.

Comment: Is Windows Defender running in the emulator? It is known to revert changes to the hosts file in Windows 8

Comment: Windows Defender is disabled on the host machine. Changes to the hosts file are in effect for desktop browsers (chrome/ie) but not within the emulator.

Comment: If somebody is still looking for this - there's an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22919788/how-to-edit-windows-phone-emulator-image-hosts-file